# How do I include VL53L0X headers into my STM32L project

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

Language: C
MCU: STM32L151C8T6
IDE: Atollic TRUEstudio
Library: https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/proximity-sensors-software/stsw-img005.html

Problem: `"fatal error: vl53l0x_api.h: No such file or directory #include "vl53l0x_api.h"`

I have included the library(core & platform folder) that was extracted from "en.STSW-IMG005" into my project, I have checked my [build settings > include directories] and both the folders are there, however it keeps failing to compile.

It always show "fatal error: vl53l0x_api.h" but it jumps from file to file every time I compile eg. "vl53l0x_api_core.c", "vl53l0x_api_calibration.c", etc.

Reason why I must use the library provided by STM is because they did not release the I2C registers for this distance sensor, so I'm forced to use their library. I have tried referencing guides provided for **VL53L1X** but it didnt quite work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the path where the header file is to the project. Right click on the project > properties > build  > paths and symbols

Comment: Ok so I have solved the compilation problem, it was due to me not adding the path to the specific sub folder, I added the main folder's path thinking that it will include all the sub folders. Now that that is out of the way, I find all sorts of compilation error when I try to call any function. I don't think that a library would be so user unfriendly, so I must be missing something here.